# Instrumental variables analysis with exclusion restriction violation

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables, variable

I am working with data from a randomized experimental study in which the random assignment of units is used as an instrument. However, there are four endogenous variables (treatments) which are hypothesized to affect each of the outcomes, not just one, so wouldn't this violate the Exclusion restriction which says that Z affects the outcome Y only through X? Since there are multiple endogenous variables. What can be done to still be able to use IV analysis? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify how the randomization works here? Are the treated units being encouraged to take up a particular treatment? Or are they offered all 4 treatments and then chose between one, more than one, or none?

Comment: The units are supposed to take on all four treatments but it is not guaranteed they will.

Answer (score 1):

I believe with four endogenous variables, you would need four exogenous instruments for $E(U|Z)=0$ to hold. This is what we would call a "just-identified" model as the # of instruments = # of endogenous variables. Ideally, an over-identified model allows for more tests as to the validity of your instruments. In short, you would need to find more instruments which is a dastardly task.